# CKEditor does not work in a custom folder

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have my root folder `htdocs/_` and my custom CKEditor folder `htdocs/_/ckeditor` where all my CKEditor files are in. But when I run CKEditor it looks for all the CKEditor files in `htdocs/_`

```
<textarea name='post_editor' id='post_editor' rows='10' cols='80'></textarea>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    CKEDITOR.replace('post_editor');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with the underscore in URL, so I don't know what may be wrong in your case. Did you e.g. changed the name of `ckeditor.js` file?

As a workaround, try setting `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH`. You can find more in the [Specifying the Editor Path guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath).

```
<script>
    var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'htdocs/_/ckeditor/';
</script>
<script src="htdocs/_/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```